# Cannot read property 'fetchBans' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying out a new command, which is the `unban` command. However, if I run the code below I keep getting `Cannot read property 'fetchBans' of undefined`. I'm currently using v12.16.3.

```
  if(!message.member.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("You dont have permission to perform this command!")


    if(isNaN(args[0])) return message.channel.send("You need to provide an ID.")
    let bannedMember = await client.guild.fetchBans(args[0])
        if(!bannedMember) return message.channel.send("Please provide a user id to unban someone!")

    let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")
        if(!reason) reason = "No reason given!"

    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission(["BAN_MEMBERS", "ADMINISTRATOR"])) return message.channel.send("I dont have permission to perform this command!")|
    message.delete()
    try {
        message.guild.guild.fetchBans(bannedMember, reason)
        message.channel.send(`${bannedMember.tag} has been unbanned from the guild!`)
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }

    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
       .setColor('RANDOM')
       .setAuthor(`${message.guild.name} Modlogs`, message.guild.iconURL)
       .addField("Moderation:", "unban")
       .addField("Moderated on:", `${bannedMember.username} (${bannedMember.id})`)
       .addField("Moderator:", message.author.username)
       .addField("Reason:", reason)

        let sChannel = message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name === "modlog")
        sChannel.send(embed)
```

Comment: `message.guild.guild` does not exist which is why you are getting that error

Comment: Thanks for browsing the code! I changed it but I'm still getting the same error.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchBans' of undefined

Comment: Could it be because you call `message.delete()` before it? It seems like maybe that should be called after.

Comment: With or without it, I'm still getting the exact same error.

Comment: Then `message.guild` does not exist either

Answer (score 0):

`message.guild.guild` does not exist, remove the second `guild`:

```js
message.guild.fetchBans(bannedMember, reason)
```

Comment: Thanks for checking the code, however, I'm still getting the same error.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetchBans' of undefined