# how to fetch a user in the banlist (duplicate) discordjs

Tags: discord.js

Im trying to check a user in the ban list to see whether that user is banned or not from the server. ive been using this code here

```
let banMember = message.mentions.members.first() || await bot.users.fetch(args[0])

let bansUser = message.guild.fetchBans(banMember)

 if(!bansUser) {
// code for ban
} else {
message.channel.send("This Member is already banned")
```

The issue i have right now is the user is not banned in the server but when i do this command it shows the user is banned when hes not.

Dont know where i did wrong in my code.

i have tried researching the following posts as well:

[Cannot read property 'fetchBans' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61809975/cannot-read-property-fetchbans-of-undefined)

[How do I check if a user is banned or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732330/how-do-i-check-if-a-user-is-banned-or-not)

Progress 1: the else got triggered when the user is in the guild. so i decide to reverse the `bansUser.size > 1`  to `bansUser.size < 1` which the bot finally banned the user. But after banning the user whenn i try to trigger the else by banning again the else didnt come up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Guild#fetchBans` fetches something from the API. So you need to await it.

You can do this by writing (The function needs to be async)

```
let bansUser = await message.guild.fetchBans(banMember).catch(e => { /* Code when the user isn't banned */ })
```

or by writing this:

```
message.guild.fetchBans(banMember).then((bansUser) => {
    // Code when the user is banned
}).catch(error => { /* Code when the user isn't banned */ })
```

Comment: Hello, i have attampted to put await in there as what you have told me, the results didnt improve for kind of reason. i try to ban a user in my server again and it still says this user is banned when hes not! Thanks for your answer tho.

Comment: I edited my answer because I forgot that you need to check for the size of the collection, which is getting returned from the method `fetchBans`

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply here. Ive edited my code to bansUser.size < 1. The result is still the same. But after putting it in webstorm have returned me this warning: Unresolved variable size. Thanks!

Comment: Then you didn't implement the await correctly. Can you send me your code via pastebin or hastebin if it is to long?

Comment: Hello, thanks for replying. This is my code here at pastebin
https://pastebin.com/gZgwNH3m

Comment: I forgot that the method `fetchBans` fetches all bans and not only a specific ban. You should use: [fetchBan](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchBan) But caution this won't return a Collection. This one returns [BanInfo](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/BanInfo) and it is a Promise. If there is no ban an error occurs. I changed my answer to the new "Info". My fault

Comment: Hello, i have updated my code as shown below:
https://pastebin.com/4CekLLCB
the problem still exists.

Comment: You still have fetchBans in your code. Although I edited my code to fetchBan from fetchBans

Comment: yep, my fault there. Thankyou Xandrrr, the thing worked now perfect!